# SSRS : Format (indentation) new lines in a textbox using expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

In SSRS, I have a textbox with value as below expression, Expression is within a single textbox and I need format the lines in that single textbox.

```
 = "Test Example " 
    & vbcrlf & SPACE(10)+ "First Name," + "  Middle Name," + " Last Name"
    & vbcrlf & SPACE(10)+ "Address 1," + " Address 2," + " Address 3"
    & vbcrlf & SPACE(10)+ "Instructions: " + " Please select your country from the list below so we can display the correct prices, delivery times and shipping costs for your shipping destination."
```

Current Output is:

```
 Test Example
       First Name, Middle Name, Last Name
       Address 1, Address 2, Address 3
       Instructions: Please select your country from the list below so we can 
    display the correct prices, delivery times and shipping costs for your 
    shipping destination.
```

I have to format the text to start at same point and Expected Output is below:

```
Test Example
       First Name, Middle Name, Last Name
       Address 1, Address 2, Address 3
       Instructions: Please select your country from the list below so we 
       can display the correct prices, delivery times and shipping costs for 
       your shipping destination.
```

How can I change the expression to get expected output?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the one use for the **Hanging Indent** property. The trick to use a negative number to get what you want.

[image: Before text]

[image: Set the HANGING INDENT property]

[image]

I'm not sure how this renders in various outputs - I think the formatting might be lost in Excel.

Comment: Initially, it didn't work as SPACE (10) was overriding Hanging Indent Property. Removed Space(10) from my code and it worked. Thank you so much!!